# where to Storing a managed object in custom app hosted in cumulocity

Tags: cumulocity

Where to store the managed object for the custom angular 6 App which is hosted inside the cumulocity

Thanks
BA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store metadata for your applications the inventory is the right place.
A good approach is to give your object either a unique type for some unique flag.

```
{
  "type": "myUniqueType",
  "myUniqueFlag": {}
}
```

That way you can easily query it again with either type=myUniqueType or fragmentType=myUniqueFlag

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you could share some reference or documentation in the cumulocity it would be easy for us to proceed further.

Comment: This is the correct API: http://cumulocity.com/guides/reference/inventory